# Jquery dropdown hiding behind the wrapper div

Tags: jquery, html, css

As i am working on jquery dropdown list for my games site. I got struck at one issue. My dropdown goes behind the wrapper div when i mouse over it on the dropdown. Can anyone tell me what's wron with my code. See my sample code and image.
[image]

Code:

```
<div class="cat_btn">
                  <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
                <ul class="sub_menu">
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
ul.dropdown                         { position: relative; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                   
                              -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
ul.dropdown li                      { font-weight: bold; float: left; zoom: 1; background: #ccc; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                    
                              -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; /*width: 100px; height: 30px;*/}
ul.dropdown a:hover                 { color: #000; }
ul.dropdown a:active                { color: #ffa500; }
ul.dropdown li a                    { display: block; padding: 4px 8px; border-right: 1px solid #333;
                                      color: #222; }
ul.dropdown li:last-child a         { border-right: none; } /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover,
ul.dropdown li:hover                { background: #F3D673; color: black; position: absolute; }
ul.dropdown li.hover a              { color: black; }

ul.dropdown ul                      { width: 220px; visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                     
                              -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
ul.dropdown ul li                   { font-weight: normal; background: #f6f6f6; color: #000; 
                                      border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; float: none; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                   
                              -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
                                  /* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */

ul.dropdown ul li a                 { border-right: none; width: 100%; display: inline-block; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;                   
                              -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;}
```

Comment: try giving `z-index` to `ul.dropdown`

Comment: Seeing what other css you have applied to the wrapping elements would be useful *(i.e. cat_btn or it's parents like the div that wraps your header elements)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:1000` to the class `ul.dropdown`

Comment: Have you given z-index with lesser value to that jquery plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `overflow:hidden` applied to `cat_btn` (or any of it's parents?) If so, this will be what is cutting off any child element from `overflowing`.

### additional

With regards to my comment, in order to fix your other problem, you could implement the following:

```
<div class="cat_btn">
  <ul class="dropdown">
     <li class="dropdown-item">
       <a href="#">Categories</a>
       <ul class="sub_menu">
         <li><a href="#">Ben10</a></li>
         ...
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="dropdown-item">
       ...
```

With the above you can then specifically target the LIs you need with `ul.dropdown li.dropdown-item:hover` which wont affect the other LIs within.

As I've also stated, you could use:

```
ul.dropdown > li:hover
```

Which will only select the immediate children of `ul.dropdown` but this isn't supported by older browsers.

Comment: Yes i have a overflow:hidden applied to content1 div. Now its working. but after removing the overflow:hidden from the content1 div. The last element of the dropdown gets hiding when mouseover the dropdown menu's any element. Any suggestions.

Comment: In order to give further help, I'd need to see the other markup and css that is applied.

Comment: Hi pebbl, if you check this link (http://www.toon10.com/) then you will get clear idea.. Mouse over on the Categories button in the header section and mouseover it on the dropdown first element.

Comment: As a quick guess, it looks to be this line of your css `ul.dropdown li:hover { background: #F3D673; color: black; position: absolute; z-index:1000;}` - this is affecting any hovered `li` by making it absoluted, which will affect the layout of other items on the page. I understand you are using this to make you menu appear but you don't want it to affect the LIs further inside the menu (which it currently does)... you can change this by either adding a specific class to your first LIs or change the selector to `ul.dropdown > li:hover` *(this latter item wont work on older browsers however)*